# Use REST API to search inputted text (HTML + PHP)

Tags: php, html, rest

I don't know much about web development and am struggling to make a simple search page. All the search engine coding is functional and will be called through a REST API.

My HTML page is this one:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input id="search_query" type="text" placeholder="Insert the text" /> 
  </div>
  <div><button id="search" type="submit">Go</button></div>
</div>

<div id="results"> </div>
```

And the PHP call is done like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'unirest-php/lib/Unirest.php';
 $response = Unirest\Request::post(
 "MY_URL", 
    array(
      "X-Domino-Api-Key" => "MY_API_KEY",
      "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    ),
 json_encode(array("parameters" => [ "THE_QUERY" ]))
);

print_r($response->code);
print_r($response->headers);
print_r($response->body);
?>
```

I got stuck on how to link them, how to get the query from the input and how to place the results in the correct place.

Maybe it is very easy but I really don't  have experience in web development, so I would appreciate if it is possible to keep the solution simple.

Thanks!

Comment: And where's the correct place?

Comment: It would be in the div "results"

Answer (score 0):

Google "HTML form".  Your search form is missing the **form** part.  Here is the HTML, assuming your php file is called "search.php":

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET" target="someFrame">
    <input name="search_query" type="text"> 
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<iframe name="someFrame">
    <!--results will appear in here-->
</iframe>
```

And in your PHP you will need to change:

```
json_encode(array("parameters" => [ "THE_QUERY" ]))
```

to

```
json_encode(array("parameters" => $_GET["search_query"] ))
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you for the answer. But I still can't see the results called from the REST API. It seems that when the GET is called, it retrieve a "page not found" error... any idea why this happen? When I test the API call on git hub I can retrieve the results, just can't put them on the webpage.

Comment: Make sure the path in `action="search.php"` is correct - in the code I gave, I was assuming your HTML file is in the same directory as the "search.php" file.  You might also want to change the content of "search.php" to simply `echo 'hello world';` for now to make sure it works.

Comment: Hi, it worked but I got an error message: "Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/a3553542/public_html/search.php on line 3". Maybe the server I am using does not support the characters I retrieve from my API (I have Portuguese language in it, with accents and 'ç')

Comment: Line 3 of that file has "Unirest

Comment: Line 3 of that file has "Unirest\Request", which uses PHP "namespaces".  This was not supported prior to php version 5.3.  As well, Unirest says it requires php version 5.4 so check your php version, you need to have 5.4 or higher.

Comment: I see... the server I am using only have php 5.2... will try a different approach with curl